# Conditional statement using Long and Text fields with Python Parser of Calculate Field in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, conditional

I have 3 fields:

1. "*ISL_Numero*" - Long (values are '1', '2', '3', '4' etc.)
2. "*Subtipo_IS*" - Text (values are 'A', 'B', 'C' etc.)
3. "*Ambiente_C*" - Text (values I want to calculate)

An example of what I want:

> If "*ISL_Numero*" is **1** and "*Subtipo_IS*" is **A**, I want "*Ambiente_C*" to be **Mangue**
>
> If "*ISL_Numero*" is **1** and "*Subtipo_IS*" is **B**, I want "*Ambiente_C*" to be **Praia**
>
> If "*ISL_Numero*" is **2** and "*Subtipo_IS*" is **A**, I want "*Ambiente_C*" to be **Cascalho**
>
> And so on ...

I tried the following:

```py
Reclass(!ISL_Numero!,!Subtipo_IS!)
```

```py
def Reclass(ISLNumero,SubtipoIS):
    if ( ISL_Numero == 1 and Subtipo_IS == "A" ) :
        return "Mangue"
    elif ( ISL_Numero == 1 and Subtipo_IS == "B" ) :
        return "Praia"
    elif ( ISL_Numero == 2 and Subtipo_IS == "A" ) :
        return "Cascalho"
    else:
        return ""
```

The calculation runs with no errors but the "*Ambiente_C*" doesn't get calculated as expected, it remains blank.

Comment: the variable name in the `if` does not match the parameter name (`ISLNumero` vs `ISL_Numero `, and `SubtipoIS` vs `Subtipo_IS`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Python in ArcGIS specifically, but, as @JGH noted in their comment, the variables in your function definition (`ISLNumero` and `SubtipoIS`) must correspond to the names you use in the function body (`ISL_Numero` and `Subtipo_IS`). If there's some kind of error log in ArcGIS, I would expect to see a `NameError: name 'ISL_Numero' is not defined` from Python.

If the issue persists, as always, please provide additional details and we'll do our best to help.